# I need one option to update the other in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, filter, ng-options

I have a plunker set up http://plnkr.co/edit/fZ6akOYipzZ7ym8dliCV?p=preview

I want the first list to filter the group in the next list.  It seems like it should be simple but i cannot seem to get it to function as desired.  Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Plunker is good; but you may consider adding more details to the question on what you've tried and why it didn't work. Running your code in FF shows an error in the console "Error: Unknown provider: typeFilterProvider <- typeFilter" .  So, I would start by fixing that error and re-evaluating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://plnkr.co/edit/l63zgdyDeZnvNGVAar6P?p=preview

You need to use just filter the first array with `.filter` method on the array, and check to see if the type is equal to the other type in a function (like `get(option2)`)

```
<select id="unitTypes_speciality" name="speciality" data-role="none" data-ng-model="speciality" 
ng-options="p as p.label group by p.type for p in get(options2, type)"><option>None</option></select>

$scope.get = function(myarray, type) {
  return myarray.filter(function(value) { return value.type == $scope.type.label })
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that is exatly what I was looking for.